# How to show GUI progress for a long process?

Tags: delphi

I need to process some data and every 5-10 seconds to show a progress (I show progress in % but I also update some graphs).  I want to do this without multithreading.
The loop ca be pretty big. It can start at millions and can be as high as billions.

I could use GetTickCount:

```
const 
  RefreshEvery= 5000;

for x:= 1 to 10000000000 do
 if GetTickCount-OldTime> RefreshEvery then
 begin
   OldTime:= GetTickCount;
   if Assigned(FProgress) then FProgress(Self);
 end;
```

but calling GetTickCount in loop that executes billions of times...

Any ideas about the most efficient way of doing this?

---

Why without multithreading?
This is a big app that has a glitch in the GUI progress module. I want to fix this, repack it and deliver it without doing big changes to it that requires intensive testing again. Multithreading?... Cool, but later...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid multi-threading? It sounds like a perfect scenario to use it.

Comment: >It sounds like a perfect scenario to use it     -------  It is. I 101% agree with you. But let's do it without multithreading for the moment :)

Comment: @MartynA-I don't think it is working with OnIdle: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnIdle.html

Comment: The typical way is to do something like `if x mod 1000 = 0`, but integer division can be expensive if the rest of your loop is fast.  Bitshifting to mask off the last 10 bits of `x` (for `mod 1024`, for example) is faster - then compare with zero.  This applies whether multithreaded or not - merely the deciding condition on when to issue a progress event.

Comment: @splash-Timer is not a good idea here (I think) because the application must process its messages queue.

Comment: Did you profile? Does your program really spends significant amount of time in `GetTickCount` relative to time spent by real processing? We can not know this from your boilerplate.

Comment: How will the application process its message queue when you are doing a busy loop?

Comment: try to use Thread and SendMessage;

Comment: @LURD  `ProgressBar1.Repaint;` - doesn't need the message queue.  The app will still otherwise be unresponsive, but at least the bar will move.  A thread is still by far the best solution here, but if OP is stubbornly against it then this will work, albeit in an ugly way (and without need `ProcessMessages`).

Comment: If you going to throttle the GUI application message queue, you will not be able to show the progress too.

Comment: why not use a thread ?

Comment: A `TTimer` has no affect to the message processing, but your loop.

Comment: @splash What Altar means is that a `TTimer` simply doesn't work while you are in a busy loop.  The events don't fire until the message queue is serviced and that doesn't happen until the loop's method terminates or a call to `ProcessMessages` is made.  `TTimer` is not just a bad idea; it won't work - it cannot work.

Comment: @splash - Yes... As J explains it... TTimer won't work.

Comment: When faced with a bad solution (like doing a busy loop in the main thread), take a step back and refactor the code instead of patching. Yes, it may take a little longer to find and test a better way, but it will be good invested time.

Comment: @LURD - I agree with you. I will refactor it one day, in the next version, if this will ever be built. But for the moment is not worth it to spend several days to implement something that will not make any difference (from user's point of view). But again... I agree with you that this app needs refactoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to be about determining an efficient way of evaluating an interval at which to issue a progress update.  If you are dead-set against a threaded approach then what you are doing is fine - there is not much in the way of improving it.  In fact, the efficiency of determining an update interval is just as relevant in threaded code as well so whether threaded or not the problem is the same.

You don't seem to have an issue with the contents of `FProgress(self)` (ie : how to perform the status update), nor does this seem to be about "un-freezing" the GUI so I will not address those points.

Your options are

- `GetTickCount` -- update based on time
- `if x mod 1000 = 0` -- update based on loop variable
- (something like) `if x shl 22 = 0`  -- same as above, but a tricksy mod 1024 without division
- Per @LURD, you could also use something like `if i and $3FF = 0` for similar performance

These are almost identical in performance if your loop has any meat to it at all.  To test :

```
program Project1;

uses Windows, SysUtils;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    

var 
  i : integer;
  t0 : cardinal;
begin
  t0 := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do begin
    if t0 - GetTickCount > 1000 then;
  end;
  t0 := GetTickCount - t0;
  WriteLn('GetTickCount : ' + IntToStr(t0));

  t0 := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do begin
    if i mod 1000 = 0 then;
  end;
  t0 := GetTickCount - t0;
  WriteLn('i mod 1000 : ' + IntToStr(t0));

  t0 := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do begin
    if i shl 22 = 0 then;
  end;
  t0 := GetTickCount - t0;
  WriteLn('i shl 22 : ' + IntToStr(t0));

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Produces output (for me)

```
 GetTickCount : 3978   
 i mod 1000 :   3386   
 i shl 22 :     2184
```

The last option is about twice as performant, but if your loop is doing anything substantial at all you probably won't notice any difference.

---

Appendix :

If you need to satisfy yourself that bitshifting is an accurate way to do this :

```
program Project1;

uses SysUtils;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do begin
    if (i shl 22 = 0) <> (i mod 1024 = 0) then
      WriteLn('not the same! : ' + IntToStr(i));
  end;
  WriteLn('complete.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Note that `i shl 22` does not equal `i mod 1024`, but they are both zero for the same values of `i`.

Comment: Not that it matters - just curious. Why use "+IntToStr(t0)" when you can just as easily just do ",t0", ie. WriteLn('i shl 22 : ', t0);

Comment: @HeartWare Force of habit... I like to be explicit, I guess.  I also don't really write console applications except for small mcve's so I guess I've never really gotten friendly with `WriteLn`.

Comment: I find `i and $3FF = 0` a little bit faster than `i shl 22 = 0`.

Comment: @LURD depends on the architecture and the operands locations (register vs memory)...`AND` can have a longer latency but `SHL` can have lower reciprocal throughput.  We're talking a few clocks and that's about it. In the test above `SHL` is faster for me by about 4%.  Unless you're ready to start worrying about optimizing port usage and speculative execution I'd probably call them close to equal.  I would say that `i and $3FF` is a bit more elegant and readable, however...but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to move your busy loop into a background thread you can at least use a background thread for timing:

```
type
  TTimerThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    class var Flag: Boolean;
  end;

implementation

{ TTimerThread }

procedure TTimerThread.Execute;
begin
  Sleep(5000); // 5 seconds;
  Flag:= True;
end;
```

and check/reset `TTimerThread.Flag` in your busy loop.

Update: a better timer thread which can be terminated immediately, without up to 5 seconds waiting:

```
uses
  Windows, Classes;

type
  TimerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FEvent: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    class var Flag: Boolean;
    procedure FastTerminate;
  end;

implementation

{ TimerThread }

procedure TimerThread.Execute;
begin
  FEvent:= CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
//  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
  while not Terminated do begin
    if WaitForSingleObject(FEvent, 5000) = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      Flag:= True
    else
      Terminate;
  end;
  CloseHandle(FEvent);
end;

procedure TimerThread.FastTerminate;
begin
  SetEvent(FEvent);
end;
```

Comment: Hm... I like it. Is it faster if I declare Flag as a var instead of property? I have to test Flag 10000000 times... and set it to false... (but setting it does not happen as often as reading it).

Comment: Declare it as class var for the least overhead.

Comment: Maybe add a `while not (Terminated)` in the `Execute` method... save restarting the thread each time and just have it run until you terminate it.

Comment: @Altar This still leaves a comparison in your loop `if Flag then...` and this will be no faster than `if i shl 22 then` - it's basically a few uops and that's it.  In fact, it may even be slower since `i` will be on the stack and `Flag` will not - could increase cache misses.

Comment: well just setting `Terminate:= True` is not very good; you need to create an event and use `WaitForSingleObject` instead of `Sleep` to terminate it gracefully.

Comment: @user246408 No you don't.  Setting `Terminate` does not kill a thread, it will still exit gracefully.

Comment: After up to 5 seconds of waiting till it wakes up. I can't call it 'exit gracefully'.

Comment: @user246408 Fair enough.  It sounded like you were suggesting that `Terminate` would kill the thread, that was my only objection.  Agreed your new solution is tidier.

Comment: Hmm, OP wanted a solution without multithreading, yet accepting such a solution. Your answer is fine, but the underlaying problem with a busy loop persists.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant approach or rather somewhat dirty, but it's working **and** (in contrast to the other answers) it keeps the GUI responsive!

The overhead of calling `Application.ProcessMessages` should not be so *gigantic* as commented below if you use something like the `x mod 1000 = 0` condition which can be tweaked as needed. Furthermore we don't know how computationally intensive the "processing of the data" really is and it's not improbable that the real impact of `Application.ProcessMessages` is minimal.

```
procedure TForm2.CancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCanceled := true;
end;

procedure TForm2.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
  timer: TTimer;
begin
  timer := TTimer.Create(self);
  timer.Interval := 5000;
  timer.OnTimer := HandleTimer;
  for x:= 1 to 10000000000 do
  begin
    if (x mod 1000 = 0) then
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    inc(FProgress);
    if FCanceled then
      break;
  end;
  timer.Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.HandleTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(FProgress);
end;
```

Comment: Servicing the message queue on every iteration is going to be much more expensive than simply calling `GetTickCount`, not to mention that introducing `ProcessMessages` is opening a whole other can of worms...

Comment: @Altar Yes you are right, but how do you want to avoid that your GUI is freezing while your are in the loop without using threads?

Comment: @Altar yes, that refreshes the progress bar, but the rest of your GUI is frozen and you can't cancel your loop.

Comment: @J... of course you are all right, this is bad style, but how do you cancel the loop?

Comment: @Altar OK, then I must return: "This (only refreshing the progress bar) is a BAD solution" ;-)

Comment: @splash - In the end, your solution is slower than mine, not faster.